# Apache2 Reverse Proxy to Nextcloud Not Loading Login Page

Tags: apache2, proxy, nextcloud, reverse-proxy

I am relatively new to both Nextcloud and Apache, so I am probably just missing something simple. I am running the Nextcloud snap on an Ubuntu 22.04 server and trying to use a separate Apache server to reverse proxy to Nextcloud.  It seems to be partially working, but instead of actually going to the Nextcloud login screen, it goes to a text-only page with nothing but a link to the Nextcloud website.

Here is the Apache config:

[image: Apache2 config]

Nextcloud loads as expected when going directly to the Nextcloud server:

[image]

But this is the page that loads if I try to access it through the proxy at https://mydomainname.com/nextcloud:

[image]